# ACL tool for audit of Ubuntu production servers

Tags: server, software-recommendation

In my production environment, I have close to 10 Ubuntu 12.04 Servers and I want to get the list of users from them. I am looking for some kind of script or tool (non-gui) to get the same. Yes, I can get the list from /etc/passwd and /etc/groups files but it would be good to have a tool or script to do this due to the following reasons.

1. I have right now 10 systems in Ubuntu and 30 systems in Windows 2003. I am recommending my organization and IT to move all the systems to Ubuntu except the one running MS SQL server
2. We do not have good Ubuntu admins with us and they should not mess up with the system if I give some manual commands
3. I also need to find out date of creation of user, group, password standards like strength, expiry etc

Please help me as I want to automate the process and get the list on weekly basis from IT team.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I publishing the answer to this question as I got answer from a different website on how to audit and harden the Ubuntu machines. The below website scripts are very good and useful.

[Rootkit](http://www.rootkit.nl/projects/lynis.html)

The project name is lynis.